# Magento: manual Login not working

Tags: php, magento

I need to manually login Users which are already logged in at a different page (with synced userdata). So I tried to send login data to a magento controller and manually login the user. The script for login looks like this:

```
$customerId = $_GET['u'];
$password = $_GET['p'];
$localCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerNumber)
        ->load();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($localCustomer->getData()[0]['entity_id']);
umask(0);
ob_start();
session_start();
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->login($customer->getData('customer_id'), $password);
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
header('Location: '.$forwardUrl);
```

This works nicely in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason, it doesn't in Internet Explorer 11 and I can't seem to understand why. If I query data from customer/session after this, they are there, but as soon as I navigate to the start page, I'm no longer logged in. Only in Internet Explorer, works perfectly with normal browsers.

Any ideas, hints, as to why this is happening? I'm getting desperate.

Comment: are you sure you are getting username and password with GET method? and try once ob_start() at the top of page. It also may be cookie set issue in IE. Please check once that settings too.

Comment: I like the part "works perfectly with normal browsers."

Comment: If I weren't getting username and password it wouldn't work in Firefox or Chrome. What cookie settings exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

function loginUser( $email, $password )

    require_once ("app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
    $customer->setStore($store);
    try {
           $customer->loadByEmail($email);
           $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
           $session->login($email, $password);
    }catch(Exception $e){

    }


  } 
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't work. The problem stays the same, in Internet Explorer I am not logged in after visiting the page